# How to Load Image on "Edit product" using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a inventory CRUD module for products in ASP.NET MVC. When inserting new product in the database I have to load an image for each product.

This is what I have and works great:
[image]

My problem is when I want to edit an existing product in a given Id and when editing a product Text successfully loads but Image does not. The problem is I do not know how to.

[image]

This is my code:

*Inserting a new product:*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NuevoProducto", "Inventario", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = 
"multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleInputFile">Imagen</label>
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="custom-file">
       <input type="file" id="file" name="Image" class="custom-file-input" multiple onchange="GetFileSize()" />
         <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Elija Imagen</label>

       </div>
        </div>
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

          <div class="col-2">
     <p>Tamaño de Imagen</p>
     </div>
    </div>

}


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NuevoProducto(ProductoViewModel viewModel)
    {

        string path = "";
        HttpPostedFileBase archivo = Request.Files["Image"];

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (archivo != null && archivo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), Path.GetFileName(archivo.FileName));
                archivo.SaveAs(path);

            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid) 
            { 
            var producto = viewModel.Producto;
            producto.FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now;
            producto.Estado = true;
            producto.Imagen = viewModel.Image.FileName;
            _productosRepository.Add(producto);
            TempData["Message"] = "¡El Producto se ha INSERTADO con éxito!";
            return RedirectToAction("Productos");
            }
        }

        viewModel.Iniciar(_productosRepository);
        return View(viewModel);

    }

public class ProductoViewModel
{

    public Producto Producto { get; set; } = new Producto();

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Se necesita una imagen.")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }

}
```

*This is my code for editing a product but image doesn't load:*

```
public ActionResult ModificarProducto(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var producto = _productosRepository.Get((int)id, incluideRelatedEntities: false);

        if (producto == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        //necesito capturar los  datos y almacenarlos en viewmodel
        var viewModel = new ProductoEditViewModel()
        {
            Producto = producto
        };
        viewModel.Iniciar(_productosRepository);

        return View(viewModel);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ModificarProducto(ProductoEditViewModel viewModel)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var producto = viewModel.Producto;
            _productosRepository.ModificarProducto(producto);
            TempData["Message"] = "¡El Producto se ha MODIFICADO con éxito!";
            return RedirectToAction("DetallesProducto", "Inventario", new {viewModel.Id});

        }

        viewModel.Iniciar(_productosRepository);


        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I save database the path of the image stored in Images Folder and show images in the list by using a
`<img src="~/Images/@producto.Imagen" height="100" />`. I do not know how to load Image in the edit view and make it easy for my client because saving in the edit view image goes empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After click on edit button, store image name and path in tempdata and during update get it back from tempdata.

Comment: What if user uploads new image and replace the existing loaded one? will it work?

Comment: I am using `HttpPostedFileBase `

Comment: Please share your view to which displays all data

Comment: Check your code, in your action method ModificialProducto(int? Id), when you are initializing productoEditViewModel, you are just assigning back Product property is only not Image property. Can you check that ??

Comment: I got you but perhaps I am looking for when loading a view I want the `input file` populated with image path. I think I have to code this using JS. I have already the image path.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `preview div` on your edit form. example below:

```
<div class="custom-file">
   <div class="preview-image-section">
      <img src='@Model.Image' class="preview-image" /> 
   </div>
   <input type="file" id="file" name="Image" class="custom-file-input" multiple onchange="GetFileSize()" />
     <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Elija Imagen</label>

   </div>
```

and in your javascript code, if you wanna dislay the selected image by choosing button:

```
function GetFileSize() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

        var FR = new FileReader();

        FR.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
            $(".preview-image").attr('src', e.target.result);
        });

        FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }

   //your code here
 }
```

Comment: Well I think I was not enough specific. You are trying to show the image but I that is not what I am looking for, because user needs to replace the image if needed in the `input type=file`

Comment: I think it could be good if I populate the `input file` with a given loaded image path. ( not at image drawing)

Comment: As your specified, I think the image should be uploaded before showing up.